# Run CLI command on a windows EC2 Instance using c#

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

i'm programming a system in .net that designed to run an execution file on a remote machine via cli command, in this case, Amazon EC2 windows instance. I've searched the AWS .net SDK and found no request of sending a shell command to the machine or something similar.
Would appreciate your help on that one.

Comment: A good question, you have to remember of course that AWS gives you a virtual machine and that's it - there's no magic framework for controlling it, installing components, .. you get RDC and that's about it

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Remote Powershell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff700227.aspx) which itself takes advantage of [WinRM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384426(v=vs.85).aspx).